# How to do form field repetition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, hyperlink, field, eventhandler

I got a form with a list of games I'm asking people to add that they've played.

It says "Add Game" with a hyperlink which has an event handler onClick which directs to a JavaScript function - it only does this once but I want it to do this as many times as the user decides to add games - without any limits - how can this be done?

Here are the screen shot images followed by the code:

http://i59.tinypic.com/16jk1nt.png

http://i59.tinypic.com/2zzntoo.png

Here's the JavaScript code for the above images:

```
function addFields1(){
        var container = document.getElementById("container1");
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Add Game"));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    }
```

Here's the HTML form for the above JavaScript code:

```
    <input type="text" id="member1" name="member1" value="">Add Game<br />
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields1()">Add Game</a>
    <div id="container1"/>
```

When I click the "Add Game" hyperlink, it enters a blank input box only once while I want it to enter it as many times as I keep on clicking the "Add Game" hyper link. Also, I would like the "Add Game" hyper link to replicate itself every time I click that link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <script>
        function addFields1(){
            var container = document.getElementById("container1");

            //remove button
            var addGameButton = document.getElementById("filldetails");
            container.removeChild(addGameButton);

            //create and insert input/text
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Add Game"));
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            //create and insert button
            addGameButton = document.createElement("a");
            addGameButton.id="filldetails"
            addGameButton.href="#";
            addGameButton.onclick=function(){addFields1();};
            addGameButton.text="Add Game";
            container.appendChild(addGameButton);

        }

    </script>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="container1">
                <input type="text" id="member1" name="member1" value="">Add Game<br />
                <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields1()">Add Game</a>
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnx for the assistance mate

Comment: i don't got enough credits to do that - apparently i need more points or somethang